FEM: Should I updates inner variable during iterations for Newton-Raphson's method?
When you apply Newton-Raphson's method for FEA about quasi static mechanical analysis, will you update all inner vaiables not only stress, strain, but also variables that depends on deformation path during N-R's iterations?
What I am concerning is if I update for example the time integrated plastic strain like this:
$$\bar{\varepsilon}^{p}:=\int_{t'=0}^{t'=t}|\dot{\varepsilon}^{p}|dt$$, what does this plastic strain accumulated during N-R iterations means as the physical value. Is introducing N-R iterations equivalent to changing the deformation path from intended path?

What is the motivation of your analysis?

I am trying to make my FEM program for elasto-plastic deformation analysis. At first I was making it based on explicit method, but I want to use Newton-Raphson's method from the aspect of accuracy.
But my constitutive equations has dependencies on the deformation-path dependent value like $\bar{\varepsilon}^{p}$. So I want to know those variables should be updated during N-R iterations.

If some required variables are path-dependent, you should definitely update them. It may not be necessary in every single N-R iteration, but you should definitely do it after every convergence before next load increase. Unconverged N-R iterations are not part of the 'path' in path-dependance.
One variable that does not need to be updated all the time is stiffness. While updated stiffness should in general lead to less iterations, stiffness updates may be computationally expensive. Also, when you are approaching limit load, where actual stiffness is getting close to zero, the initial stiffness may be more numerically stable than actual stiffness and you can reach slightly higher load with it.

Thank you for your comments. I agree that I must update path-dependent variables in every load increment. If unconverged N-R iterations are not part of the "path"-dependence, when in the loop of N-R iterations should I update them?
Actually those path-dependent variable appears the right hand side of the global stiffness matrix equation (Ku=f+g(epsilon^p) ). epsilon^p also changes its value based on the stress value that changes during N-R loop. I thought I have to update them every N-R iterations. or neglect g(epsilon^p) during N-R loop.

Every N-R iteration is basically a guess followed by a check. What you are checking in path-dependent scenarios is a possible path between the last converged solution and the guess solution based on the new load increment. This check may involve considering path-dependence along the whole possible path, but I would not call this update. If the new guess solution is not good enough, you are still starting next guess path from the last converged solution. If on the other hand the new guess solution is acceptable, it becomes the new last converged solution.

Thank you. I understood that I should distinguish between N-R iterations and loading increments.
